# Are the Voyager spacecraft rotating in space or are they completely still?

Tags: space-mission, nasa, solar-system-exploration

Are the [Voyager spacecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_program) completely still (fixated) when travelling through space or are they a little unstable because they are travelling at high velocities?

Comment: See http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/basics/bsf11-2.php

Comment: It says that Voyager 1 and 2 used "3-axis stabilization" to keep themselves pointing in particular directions. The alternative is to keep the whole thing spinning, like a big gyroscope. I don't know much about it, to be honest, but it sounds interesting. If I read enough to understand it properly, I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: Why would a high speed make it unstable?

Comment: While taking pictures, it would need to be non-rotating. While traveling between planets, it would probably rotate since it would be easier to keep the antenna pointed in the right direction.

Comment: There's also a surprisingly long wiki page - this subject is known as attitude control - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_control

Comment: and @HDE226868, in addition considering Einsteinian or even classical relativity, how it is it that Voyager is even at high speed?  from Voyager's point-of-view it's perfectly still.

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson Exactly.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson this is what I thought its just this video is messing with my logic as there is really no point in the video when picture would be still. I would expect to see nice timelapse of smooth movement but this is not the case on the video.

Answer (score 2):

Although the craft can be turned if necessary, the Voyager probes are not intentionally rotating.  They use small thrusters that try to zero out any rotations.

These thrusters aren't infinitely precise, nor are the instruments that drive them.  So there is some error in the firing that means the probe has a (small) residual rotation.  Instead of having a perfectly fixed direction, it will slowly drift away from the intended attitude over time.  When the residual rotation moves the platform too far from the antenna pointing at earth, the thrusters fire to to return the alignment.

This error in the rotation rate has nothing to do with the speed of the probe.

Comment: aha, look what the cat dragged in! [Could the Voyager spacecraft be spin-stabilized to keep their high gain antennas pointing towards the Sun and Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36006/12102)